# Java: How can I access a class's field by a name stored in a variable?

Tags: java, class, field

How can I set or get a field in a class whose name is dynamic and stored in a string variable?

```
public class Test {

    public String a1;
    public String a2;  

    public Test(String key) {
        this.key = 'found';  <--- error
    } 

}
```

Comment: Although there are valid reasons for doing this, if you are trying to do this you are probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: Your code example is very confusing.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have to use reflection:

- Use [`Class.getField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-) to get a [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) reference. If it's not public you'll need to call [`Class.getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) instead
- Use [`AccessibleObject.setAccessible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-) to gain access to the field if it's not public
- Use [`Field.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) to set the value, or one of the similarly-named methods if it's a primitive

Here's an example which deals with the simple case of a public field. A nicer alternative would be to use properties, if possible.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class DataObject
{
    // I don't like public fields; this is *solely*
    // to make it easier to demonstrate
    public String foo;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        // Declaring that a method throws Exception is
        // likewise usually a bad idea; consider the
        // various failure cases carefully
        throws Exception
    {
        Field field = DataObject.class.getField("foo");
        DataObject o = new DataObject();
        field.set(o, "new value");
        System.out.println(o.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: set() asks me for two parameters, Object and value,
why not just value? what's the first parameter ? - Field classField = this.getClass().getField(objField.getName());
    classField.set(Object,Value)

Comment: @ufk: The first parameter is the object for which you want to set the field. Note that you got the `Field` instance by querying the class - there is nothing that links it to a particular instance of that class.

Comment: and if it is not a primitive ? In my case it's another class (an array of classes which I want to set/change/allocate)

Answer (score 2):

```
Class<?> actualClass=actual.getClass();

Field f=actualClass.getDeclaredField("name");
```

The above code would suffice .

```
object.class.getField("foo");
```

Unfortunately the above code didn't work for me , since the class had empty field array.