# Is there a way to set member variables of an instance based on a given string?

Tags: java

I would like to do something similar to the following... something like this is kind of easy in dynamic languages, but I'm wondering if it's possible in Java.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public void setMember(String memberName, String memberValue) {
        // look at memberName, see that it is "name", and then set this.name to whatever memberValue is.
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that would work, but then I have to type that for every member name... I'm trying to avoid having to type similar code over and over again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How can I access a class's field by a name stored in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127197/java-how-can-i-access-a-classs-field-by-a-name-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for something like a `Map<>`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe misunderstanding, but you could just use

```
if ("name".equals(memberName)) this.name = memberValue;
```

But in a more generic sense you can use reflection to set values

```
Field nameFld = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
nameFld.setAccessible(true);
nameFld.set(this, memberValue);
```

Comment: This sounds about what I'm looking for... reflection, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Cool, please accept it as the answer @BlaineLafreniere